# Best way to implement fixed size array in C++

Tags: c++, c++14

I am trying to implement a fixed size array of 32 bit integers, but the size is determined at runtime so it has to be heap allocated. Would it be more efficient to use a c++ `std::vector` and use `vector.reserve()` or should I use the conventional way of doing it using `new int32_t[size]`? Additionally, would it be worth using a `unique_ptr` with the conventional method using `new`?

Comment: Start with `std::vector`. If it turns out to be the wrong choice, unlikely, you'll find out when profiling the code.

Comment: Sidenote: Don't use `new` with `unique_ptr` unless you have really strange requirements. Prefer `std::make_unique`.

Comment: Side-side note: [`reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) allocates storage, but it doesn't set up `vector` to fully use it. If you want the usual array-style behaviour with `[]` access, you want to use [`resize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) or one of the constructors that specifies an initial size. `reserve` is mostly used when you want to avoid unnecessary reallocations when you're inserting elements into the `vector`.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` is aware of arrays and `delete[]`. You can use use `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` as a safe pointer to a dynamically allocated array and `std::make_unique<int[]>(n);` to dynamically create an array of size `n` equivalent to `new int[n];`. `auto ptr = std::make_unique<int[]>(10);` is a safe equivalent to `auto ptr = new int[10];`. Don't use `std::unique_ptr<int>` to refer to an array as the wrong `delete` will be used on destruction.

Comment: Note: If you are intentionally trying to avoid value initialization, you cannot use `std::make_unique`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would just be re-implementing `std::vector`. Probably badly because it takes years to figure out all the little corner cases and implement them correctly.